# MySQL Injection bypassing dots(.) and commas(,)

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, kohana

I got SQL Injection in a client's site but not able to dump any data. I can execute sleep() with query

`1 AND sleep(10)`

But every time my query contains either a dot(.) or comma(,) the server redirects to 404. For example `mysql.users` or `information_schema.tables` shouldn't work. I know about comma bypass technique but stuck with the dot(.) I am sure its not firewall since its filtering only these 2 characters so probably the backed framework Kohana is messing with it.

Comment: Pardon me, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Yeah. how to bypass that dot and commas filter together :)

Answer (score 0):

Kohana is deprecated and discontinued since 2017 and doesn't get any updates/bug-fixes/support since then, please consider upgrading to [Koseven](https://github.com/koseven/koseven/tree/master) (shouldn't be much work). If your issue still occurs / you need help feel free to ask Koseven Team. As for that i am sorry that i couldn't answer your question directly, but i hope i could help at least a bit.